# How to read a large .jl file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read the following dataset and turn it into a pandas dataframe: 
https://www.kaggle.com/marlesson/meli-data-challenge-2020

It is a file with lines with the following format:

```
{'event_info': '...', 'event_timestamp': '...', 'event_type': '...'}
{'event_info': '...', 'event_timestamp': '...', 'event_type': '...'}
{'event_info': '...', 'event_timestamp': '...', 'event_type': '...'}
```

I've been trying the following but it takes too long (+60min):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import fileinput
import json

%%time

df = pd.DataFrame()
with fileinput.input(files='/kaggle/input/meli-data-challenge-2020/train_dataset.jl') as file:
    for line in file:
        conv = json.loads(line)
        df = df.append(conv, ignore_index=True)
df.head()
```

In this code, it reads the file line by line as a string, turns each one of them into json, and then appends it into the dataframe.
Is there any way to turn the dataset into a pandas dataframe faster?

Comment: Is there a connection to the Julia programming language in this question apart from the file ending `.jl`, which coincides with the standard file ending for Julia scripts? If not it's probably best to remove the tag.

Answer (score 7):

The file I was trying to read was a JSON file with multiple objects. Pandas `read_json()` supports a `lines` argument for data like this:

```
%%time

df = pd.read_json('/kaggle/input/meli-data-challenge-2020/item_data.jl', lines=True)

Output: CPU times: user 14.1 s, sys: 3.31 s, total: 17.4 s
Wall time: 18.6 s
```